# Assigning picture stored on file system to item selected from database

Tags: mysql, filesystems, image

I am building php my sql application and I need to associate picture to various items that are selected from database.

For example I want to have news on my web site, and I retrieve news from database, news properties can be Title, Content and Time, but I also need picture that is going to appear together with that news on a web site.

How to dynamically associate picture form file system to a selected row from database..

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Add a column to the database called 'image' or something. That is, if a news items is stored in a row, it will have a column called 'images' in it. So you can store the path (location) to the image associated with that news item it's column.

This way you can display the associated image when a news item is displayed. Also you can store more than 1 image information in the image field (as csv or serialized array or something.)

Comment: can you please look at my other question that is related to your suggestion, thanks